# Parsing xml node content in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, ksoap2

I've managed to parse xml responses from a SOAP web service when I receive it in the following format:

```
<node>data</node><node2>moredata</node2>
```

i've been using a document builder to help with this...

However, I'm now receiving the string in the following format:

```
<session id='5643' spotName='Big Bay' starRating='3'></session>
```

I literally have zero idea how to get at the session data, which is the data I would like.

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if that answer helps you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254164/1204249