# How to parse html nested tag using SAX parser of android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, sax

I have this tag in my xml :

```
<description><![CDATA[<div><b>Location:</b> PUMBA Auditorium - University of Pune</div>
<div><b>Start Time:</b> 5/15/2012 11:00 AM</div>
<div><b>End Time:</b> 5/15/2012 2:00 PM</div>
<div><b>Description:</b> <div>General B. C. Joshi Memorial Lecture 2012- Perspective on War in the 21st Century - By Lt. Gen. A. K. Singh</div></div>
<div><b>Attachments:</b> <a href="http://uopnews.unipune.ac.in/Lists/Calendar/Attachments/14/bcjoshi2012[1].pdf">http://uopnews.unipune.ac.in/Lists/Calendar/Attachments/14/bcjoshi2012[1].pdf</a><br><a href=""></a></div>
]]></description>
```

I need to remove "`<div><b>`" n want to show only content.
what should i need to do for this.?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244345/using-saxparser-to-get-info-to-more-than-one-element-android

Comment: I have already tried the above link but its giving me only this output: <div><b>Location:</b> PUMBA Auditorium - University of Pune</div> the output i want is: PUMBA Auditorium - University of Pune Start Time:5/15/2012 11:00 AM End Time:5/15/2012 2:00 PM  Description:General B. C. Joshi Memorial Lecture 2012- Perspective on War in the 21st Century - By Lt. Gen. A. K. Singh Attachments:http://uopnews.unipune.ac.in/Lists/Calendar/Attachments/14/bcjoshi2012[1].pdf. Is there any way to obtain this type of output?

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to parse again. Everything contained between `<![CDATA[`  and `]]>` is treated as character data (text) by the parser. Assuming that this text is valid xhtml, you can convert the string to a `ByteArrayInputStream` and feed it to the parser.

Android also provides the `Html` class with the `Html.fromHtml(String)` method which receives a string and returns a new string without Html tags and accordingly formatted, so you can just feed your sax-parsed string to that.